# Arithmetic error using Mutate on Flights in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

'Flights' comes with a variable called *dep_delay* (departure_delay).
I expect this to be the difference between *departure_time* and *scheduled_departure_time*. To check:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
head(flights)

mutate(flights, 
       "diff" = dep_time - sched_dep_time) %>% 
  select(., dep_time:dep_delay, diff)
```

Result:

```
       dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay  diff
      <int>          <int>     <dbl> <int>
 1      517            515         2     2
 2      533            529         4     4
 3      542            540         2     2
 4      544            545        -1    -1
 5      554            600        -6   -46
 6      554            558        -4    -4
 7      555            600        -5   -45
 8      557            600        -3   -43
 9      557            600        -3   -43
10      558            600        -2   -42
```

What is the cause for the disparity? Where is -46 onward coming from?

Thank you

Comment: What is the question exactly? `-46` is `554 - 600`.

Comment: I believe the question is why `dep_delay` says `-6` and when calculating with Forevertrip's code `diff` says `-46`.

Comment: oh right, I see, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the format of one specific dataset, and not a programming question. The formatting is explained in the package documentation

Answer (score 0):

The times are clock times, so 554 means 5:54, and 600 means 6:00.  The time difference is 6 minutes, not 554-600 = -46 minutes.